# Compute method of Datatable not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Hello I want to find sum of `DataTable` column. by using compute method.

`object taxObject = tbl_Resords.Compute("Sum(SERVICE TAX)", " ");`

this is my expression..

but it throws following exception.

```
[System.Data.SyntaxErrorException] = {"Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier."}
```

Comment: or use LINQ: `decimal tax = tbl_Resords.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("SERVICE TAX)"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column name contains spaces then enclose all the column name in square brackets

```
object taxObject = tbl_Resords.Compute("Sum([SERVICE TAX])", "");
```